# spliting and merging overlaping dateTime intervals

Tags: java, android, jodatime, intervals

I have an arrayList of dateTime intervals (of the joda-time library) and each is attached to an int value.
for example:

[(9:00,17:00,0),(17:00,19:00,25),(19:00,20:00,50),(9:00,20:00,50)]

I want to merge the intervals so none will overlap but the parts that don't over lap will become an independent interval, the int attachments will merge with each other in the overlapping parts.
in the example above I need this result:

[(9:00,17:00,50),(17:00,19:00,75),(19:00,20:00,100)]

- more than 2 intervals can overlap\contain each other
- the input will never have gaps (the intervals are split from a base interval).

another example if it helps:

input: [(8:00,16:00,0),(16:00,18:00,25),(18:00,21:00,50),(8:00,18:00,50)]

output: [8:00,16:00,50),(16:00,18:00,75)(18:00,21:00,50)]

Comment: You’re using `DateTime`? If only the time of day is of interest, shouldn’t you use `org.joda.time.LocalTime` instead?

Comment: Do it in a way similar to how you would do it by hand: whenever two intervals overlap, split into the necessary one, two or three non-overlapping intervals. Add the numbers for the overlapping part. It takes more than a few code lines, and I recommend a fairly thorough unit test. Other than that, just dive in. Happy coding.